# ORDER BY RAND() for multiple columns (shuffle content of each column vertically)

Tags: php, mysql, random, subquery, multiple-columns

I'm looking for a mysql solution to have several columns output a random field from that column.

The query I have now only selects the entire row randomly but does not randomize the separated columns.

```
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4 FROM table ORDER BY RAND() limit 4";
```

I tried subqueries but I'm not familiar with that so if anyone could help ...

Comment: Just pick a random column from your results in PHP.

Comment: Does this table have an id field of some sort?

Comment: Nevermind, even if there were one I can't think of a sane solution; and actually have a hunch that the values in the different columns should possibly be stored in separate tables.

Comment: I have an id column yes

Comment: I have updated my answer (bottom query) after reading your comment about not wanting to shuffle columns but shuffle column's content vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT CASE rnd
          WHEN 1 THEN col1
          WHEN 2 THEN col2
          WHEN 3 THEN col3
          WHEN 4 THEN col4       
       END AS col          
FROM (       
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4,
         FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1 AS rnd
  FROM mytable 
ORDER BY RAND() ) AS t
```

Expression `FLOOR(RAND() * 4) + 1` generates a random number between 1 and 4 (inclusive). The outer query uses this number to randomly pick one of the 4 columns of the table.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a44ed/1)

**Edit:**

If you want to *shuffle* columns the you can use the following query:

```sql
SELECT CASE FIND_IN_SET(1, rnd)
          WHEN 1 THEN col1
          WHEN 2 THEN col2
          WHEN 3 THEN col3
          WHEN 4 THEN col4
       END AS c1,
       CASE FIND_IN_SET(2, rnd)
          WHEN 1 THEN col1
          WHEN 2 THEN col2
          WHEN 3 THEN col3
          WHEN 4 THEN col4
       END AS c2,
       CASE FIND_IN_SET(3, rnd)
          WHEN 1 THEN col1
          WHEN 2 THEN col2
          WHEN 3 THEN col3
          WHEN 4 THEN col4
       END AS c3,
       CASE FIND_IN_SET(4, rnd)
          WHEN 1 THEN col1
          WHEN 2 THEN col2
          WHEN 3 THEN col3
          WHEN 4 THEN col4
       END AS c4
FROM (  
  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, 
         (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i ORDER BY RAND()) 
          FROM (SELECT 1 AS i UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
                SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4) t) AS  rnd
  FROM mytable) AS t
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ccc550/1)

Comment: looking at the example at fiddle I guess it does not work for me as I'm building a sentence, so I have several strings and the columns represent a part of the parsed sentence. I actually need the fileds columns shuffled vertically but not shufflled with other cols

Answer (score 2):

If every resulting row has to be independent then there is no other way than to select 16 random rows (once for each cell in your 4x4 resulting table).

```sql
SELECT 
  (SELECT col1 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS col1,
  (SELECT col2 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS col2,
  (SELECT col3 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS col3,
  (SELECT col4 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) AS col4
FROM `table`
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Yeah great this was the solution. !!

Answer (score 1):

I think it'd be simpler if you randomize the columns in PHP as well but as a fun challenge I thought I would do it like below.
It'll give you random 4 rows and randomize/shuffle the column values.

Fist it simply GROUP_CONCAT values 1,2,3,4 but randomize the order ..then extract the indexes of numbers using FIND_IN_SET..then selects the col values based on these indexes using ELT() function.

```
SELECT 
       ELT(FIND_IN_SET(1,rand_indexes),col1,col2,col3,col4) as col1,
       ELT(FIND_IN_SET(2,rand_indexes),col1,col2,col3,col4) as col2,
       ELT(FIND_IN_SET(3,rand_indexes),col1,col2,col3,col4) as col3,
       ELT(FIND_IN_SET(4,rand_indexes),col1,col2,col3,col4) as col4
FROM 
  (SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,
     (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(i ORDER BY RAND()) as indexes FROM
       (SELECT 1 as i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4)indexes
      )as rand_indexes
   FROM `table`
   )T1 
ORDER BY RAND() limit 4
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb110/1)

**UPDATE** If you want to shuffle your column vertically like you have mentioned in comment, then you can use this query it.
It basically selects first column 4 rows in random order then joins with 4 random rows of second column and so on...

```
SELECT T1.col1,T2.col2,T3.col3,T4.col4
FROM
  (SELECT col1,@order1:=@order1+1 as i 
   FROM (SELECT col1 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) O1,(SELECT @order1:=0) initialize )T1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT col2,@order2:=@order2+1 as i 
   FROM (SELECT col2 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) O1,(SELECT @order2:=0) initialize )T2
  ON T1.i = T2.i
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT col3,@order3:=@order3+1 as i 
   FROM (SELECT col3 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) O1,(SELECT @order3:=0) initialize )T3
  ON T1.i = T3.i
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT col4,@order4:=@order4+1 as i 
   FROM (SELECT col4 FROM `table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4) O1,(SELECT @order4:=0) initialize )T4
  ON T1.i = T4.i
```

[sqlfiddle shuffle columns vertically](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c3afe/15)

Comment: I have updated my answer after seeing @Giorgos Betsos 's answer FIND_IN_SET is good use here.

Comment: I have updated my answer (bottom query) after reading your comment about not wanting to shuffle columns but shuffle column's content vertically.

Answer (score 0):

This one will do but <s>I guess</s> I'm sure it's *not* performing very good:

```
select * from
    (select col1 from table order by rand()) as a, 
    (select col2 from table order by rand()) as b,
    (select col3 from table order by rand()) as c,
    (select col4 from table order by rand()) as d
order by rand()
limit 4;
```

It does a cross join on all 4 tables (giving n^4 rows) and then fetches the first 4 rows of that.

#### Update because the OP asked about the purpose of `a/b/c/d`:

The `a`, `b`, etc. are just (randomly chosen) aliases for the 4 subqueries and can be seen as (temporary) table names.
They are required for the syntax to refer to the subqueries. In this particular example they are useless, but MySQL (and probably other systems as well) needs them.

In the above statement the column names are already unique, but consider the case when column names are not uniqe and you wanted to perform some operations on the columns, like so:

```
select concat(a.col1, ' ', c.col1), b.col2, d.col2 from
    (select col1 from table order by rand()) as a, 
    (select col2 from table order by rand()) as b,
    (select col1 from table order by rand()) as c,
    (select col2 from table order by rand()) as d
where b.col2 > d.col2
order by rand()
limit 4;
```

Then these aliases `a` to `d` are *really* needed to distinguish e.g. `col1` from the 1st and 3rd subselect.

However, @PaulSpiegel's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36805266/5830574) is better than mine because I missed the `limit 1` in the subqueries.

Comment: Actually, you don't need the inner `order by` clauses, since the outer one is randomizing every possible combination anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure. Often `select col1 from table` gives the result in the same order when issued twice, although one cannot rely on that. So I thought without any `order by` this would (often) give the same n^4 rows in the same order and the outer `order by` just shuffles the order of rows, not the order whithin the columns.

Comment: Since it is a cross join, it gives every possible combination, of which you pick 4 random ones. The inner randomizations should still yield the same n^4 combinations, just in a different order. Since you are randomizing on the outside that is not needed.

Comment: I would like to try this suggestion but I'm not sure how to interpret the as a/b/c/d/ part. My goal is to read cols with separate text-strings and concatenate them.